# fatal error: mcrypt.h: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, c, openwrt, cross-compilation, header-file

I am trying to cross compile a C code which uses a header file `mcrypt.h`.
I am compiling my code in Ubuntu distribution and my target is an openwrt distribution. I am getting the below error while cross compiling,

```
fatal error: mcrypt.h: No such file or directory
 #include <mcrypt.h>
                    ^
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

For `mcrypt.h`, `libmcrypt-dev` should be installed. Installing it in your Ubuntu distribution won't help because you are into cross compilation and not the native one. Either your `sysroot` should provide that(but it's not) or you should install it by changing your root to sysroot via `chroot`.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve by doing :

`sudo apt-get install libmcrypt-dev`

and then doing :

`gem install ruby-mcrypt -v '0.2.0'`